# not getting around (list index out of range)

Tags: python-2.7, computer-science

New to python programming language. Trying to work on the following piece of code:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self, s_id, c_id, d_id,username,password,db):
        self.s_id = s_id
        self.c_id = c_id
        self.d_id = d_id        
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.db = db

s_id = sys.argv[1]
c_id = sys.argv[2]
d_id = sys.argv[3]
u_id = sys.argv[4]
p_id = sys.argv[5]
db_id = sys.argv[6]
```

but getting the below error message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Has been couple of hours but still not getting the exact issue. Tried to look online but nothing is making sense to me as of now. Any explanation to this would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you running the script with at least 6 arguments?

Comment: In Python (like in many programming languages), counting starts at 0. So you either want to access from `sys.argv[0]` to `sys.argv[5]` and then run it with 6 command line parameters or provide at least 7 command line parameters.